# Multi countries database tables and java objects

Tags: java, design-patterns

at work we have an application that, at first, had been developed for a specific country. Now a new client is interested in the application but this client is from another country. We have to change some objects to respresent the new country.

- Country 1, properties A,B,C,D,E so java and Database contains A,B,C,D,E
- New Country 2, properties A,D,F,G,H

Solutions we came up with.

Database :

- Create a new table for the new country
- Simply add F,G,H to the current table

Java :

- Make the current address abstract with A,D then create a country specific implementation (Interesting and clear but adds the pain to work with an interface thus you have to type casts all the time)
- Simply add F,G,H to the address (Seams an unclean solution knowing that the day a new country is to be added may end up with adding I,J,K to the object)
- Modify the current object to have common properties and some generic fields like info1, info2. (Seams a good solution but makes the code unclear by working with info1, info2... in business logic)

Anyone know a good pattern for this kind of problem?

Regards

Comment: If you have to type-cast when using an interface or abstract class, then you're not using polymorphism as you should. Consider using the visitor pattern.

Comment: Lets say I that I have an object per country with an abstract. I would have a factory to create a new address for a given country. What would be the best way to set property (from HTTP request without cool framework as struts ...) of an address knowing that what I have is an instance of type abstractAddress and no idea witch properties I have.

Comment: Using an abstract populateFromRequest(HttpServletRequest) method in Address, or using the visitor pattern.

Comment: What are the real advantages using the visitor pattern vs creating a static helper like AddressHelper.doSomething(AddressUS addr)?

Comment: It avoids the type casting, and allows using polymorphism instead.

Comment: Well, there must be another reason for using visitor pattern instead. The pattern needs a visitor class with visit(USAddr), visit(CANAddr) plus asks the object to know about the visitor. On ther oher hand, the static helper, may have something(USAddr), something(CANAddr) and the address has no idea the helper exists. What about decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after the clarifying comments my understanding is:

- You already have a Address class and related database table
- Each country will require a different set of address lines for each Address
- The behaviour of the code for each country is not particularly different (i.e. addresses behave in a similar way, apart from the fact that they have different address lines)

In general, I would avoid creating new classes when the differences are really just pure data. So having two different Address classes seems like a *bad idea*, regardless of whether or not you make them inherit from a single base class. Also, inheritance hierarchies don't usually map to databases very well.

I think the best solution is to store the properties for each country in a HashMap or something similar, which then determines which address lines apply for each country. For simplicity, each Address might contain a `HashMap<String,String>`, i.e. with Strings for both the keys (address line names) and values (address data).

If you do this, then you have a high degree of flexibility over what properties you set for each country, and if you add a third country at some point you might not need any code changes - just a new set of address lines.

In the database I'd represent the data in two tables: Address and AddressLine, with the obvious 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: I realize that while making changes to my question I made it unclear on the fact that the actual object in question is not Country but Address. My Bad. I like the idea of having a map for the properties but how to make it transparent to users of the class

Comment: OK that's fine..... I think my advice still holds however. Except replace Country and CountryProperty with Address and AddressLine.

Comment: What I'd like to avoid is address.getProperty("propertyName") or address.getProperty(properties.US.propertyName.getName())

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that, if that is an accurate model of your internationalised data? Also if you don't want to access address lines individually you can define a utility function like  address.getAddressLines() which returns a List<String> or something similar.

Comment: Having a map of properties is great behind but not so clear to use. I mean, if you have addressUS containing getA, getB and getC, its clear that the properties are A, B, C. What would make it clear what you can get from the properties get(what) to avoid people trying to get a US property from a Canadian address